# Image scaling issues in Firefox

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to scale images based on browser height.

It seems to be working in Chrome and Safari, but when I check it in Firefox, the images just remain their original sizes.

Here's the code that I have so far.

HTML:

```
<div class="full-width">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <div class="images">
            <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7165/6840151639_b31263de71_b_d.jpg" />
            <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7165/6840151639_b31263de71_b_d.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.full-width {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.image-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 55%;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.images {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.image-wrapper img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 50%;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

You can view a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Pywak/

Answer (score 0):

All your absolute positioning breaks proportional size calculations. There's no longer a parent/child relationship among your elements.

Answer (score 0):

Giving `position:absolute;` without `position:relative;` to a parent Container is always going to land you in problem, when you resize the browser or when the screen resolution changes.

I would suggest that instead of img tags you use them as background-images and then use the `background:contain;` || `background:cover;` property.

Comment: I do have another outter div `#wrap` that already has `position: relative;`

Answer (score 0):

I was just working through the same issue!

Since percentage is relative to the parent element, it's key that the direct parent has an explicitly specified height. So, `.images` should have a height specified in order for its children to size properly by percentage.

You can also size the height with `vh` units (relative to viewport height), but carefully and with fallbacks, as vh is not compatible with all browsers.